# What does exactly 'most frequent' mean within the filter of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search, filtering, sorting

I was curious about statistics in Java. So I've clicked on the tag and this is where I landed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Now, when I click on "Filter" I get the following options:

"Sorted by:

- Newest
- Recent activity
- Most votes
- Most frequent
- Bounty ending soon"

I am asking myself, what exactly does "most frequent" mean. If I filter with sorted by "Most frequent", it is not sorted by the views of the several questions.